# Group SMS from android app?

Tags: android, sms

I need to implement group messaging (text SMS) in my app. 
Is it possible to send group SMS from android app?

I want to fetch more than one contact numbers from device contact list and send some text to  each of them. That message should go to their inboxes as common messaging.

Comment: poor question. u should tell us what u have tried and what is ur question.

Comment: Please see the question now. I have edited so that, now it focuses the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)'s sendXXX methods to send messages. However, those allow only one addressee at a time. E.g.:

```
sendTextMessage(String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
```

The `destinationAddress` can be only a single phone number, no tricking with commas or similar will work.

So you need to send a single message for all of the destinations one-by-one.

For working with contacts, there exists a lot of tutorials. Here is the official one: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html

Comment: Thanks.. It is already implemented like that, send each SMS one by one.